# Map <C-/> on linux and windows

Tags: key-bindings

I knew that map **/** is **_** on linux, but it not work on windows.

What should I do to map it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Assuming you are talking about gVim*

You are correct about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> working on Linux but not on Windows. That is because gVim under Windows doesn't see the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> combination. You can check if Vim receives a given sequence by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> if you are using [`mswin.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#mswin%2evim)) followed the sequence, as explained in [`:help faq-20.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d20%2e4).

In [`faq-20.5`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d20%2e5) talks explicitly about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> sequences, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> isn't listed there as reliably detected by Vim.

Thus I believe you have two options:

1. select another key combination to map
2. use a external program to translate that combination into something that Vim can detect; for example, using [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

   ```
   #ifWinActive ahk_class Vim
      Capslock::Esc
   #ifWinActive
   ```

   I use the above AHK snippet to remap <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> when gVim window is active; you could try to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to something like <kbd>F12</kbd> and then map <kbd>F12</kbd> in Vim.